# Liquibase plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, liquibase

I'm not able to find any link to any [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) plugin for Eclipse. Does anybody know if it exists or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no Liquibase plug-in for Eclipse. However there is one in progress, [see the wiki](http://www.liquibase.org/ide/home).

Answer (score 0):

This download site has just worked correctly for me.

https://liquibase-eclipse-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/com.svcdelivery.liquibase.eclipse.site/